# Firebase read permission denied when using auth security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

### Data Structure:

```
root:
  lists:
    $list:
      pass: "VALU"
```

### Rules Structure:

```
"rules": {
  "lists": {
    "$list": {
      ".read": "auth.token.name === data.child('pass').val()"
    }
  }
}
```

### Javascript:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();

firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
    displayName: "VALU"
});

firebase.database().ref("lists/{$SomeList}").once('value').then([...]);
  // Throws error: permission denied
```

I'm very confused as to why the permission is denied.  I made sure that the values for the `displayName` and the `pass` were the same, so I'm not sure as to why the comparison is returning false..

**UPDATE:** It seems that the `auth` variable in the security rules is not refreshing when the `displayName` is changed, any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force token refresh on the user after updateProfile:
`firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true)`

The idToken will be updated afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I ended up using a different structure to do it, but I'm sure your solution would have worked just as well too!